# How to use custom color palette with ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, color-palette

I am trying to create a custom color palette using hex codes and use it for the "fill" aesthetic (discrete variable) for geom_bar.

Please see code below.

```
library(pacman)
p_load(tidyverse, ggplot2, RColorBrewer)

palette_new <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("white", "#154360", "#FF5733", "#FFC300", "#1ABC9C"))(5)
scales::show_col(palette)
```

[image: Plot:]

```
data(diamonds)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = color, fill = cut)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "palette_new")
```

Output, but see error message below: [image: Output]

Warning message:
In pal_name(palette, type) : Unknown palette palette_new

I have seen several questions about this on stack overflow and have tried different things that do not work. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you try `scale_colour_manual(values = palette_new)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your main problem is that `RColorBrewer` only let's you use it's pre-defined palettes. So your palette with the values you picked will actually look like this:

[image]

And both @akrun and @Specer are correct, if you use

```r
palette_new <- grDevices::colorRampPalette(
          colors = c("white", "#154360", "#FF5733", "#FFC300", "#1ABC9C"))(5)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = color, fill = cut)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = palette_new)
```

you should get a plot like this:
[image]

You will get this:

Comment: that worked well! Thank you. I was using colorRampPalette but maybe it was masked by another package; specifying grDevices:: worked like a charm. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

@akrun has the correct approach with `scale_fill_manual`:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = color, fill = cut)) +
    geom_bar() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = palette_new)
```

Since you're not using an `RColorBrewer` color palette you can be entirely explicit with `scale_colour_manual` and `scale_fill_manual`.

Comment: Thank you @Spencer Childress! This helped me quite a lot. Unfortunately, using the code above, it gave this error: Error in `f()`:
! Insufficient values in manual scale. 5 needed but only 1 provided.

So, instead of using palette_new, I just manually wrote out the hex codes and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = color, fill = cut)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FFFFFF", "#154360", "#FF5733", "#FFC300", "#1ABC9C"))